# GPS_PROVIDER Error in Android Application

Tags: android, android-location

I have created an Android app to retrieve the location. I tried to use GPS_PROVIDER,  it returned null.. But works smooth when i use NETWORK_PROVIDER..  Can any one help me fixing this?

Here is the code

> Location location =
>   locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);

The location turns null when i replace `"NETWORK_PROVIDER"` by `"GPS_PROVIDER"`..

I have added the following three permissions in manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/> 
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/> 
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_MOCK_LOCATION"/>
```

Comment: WhAt does your manifest file look like?

Comment: i have added the following three permissions in manifest

 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_MOCK_LOCATION"/>

Comment: You device must be connected via WiFi, that's why it works with NETWORK_PROVIDER

Comment: Also , add this basic permission `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_GPS"></uses-permission>`

Comment: @Lucifer `ACCESS_GPS` is not in use anymore. As far as know that was before 1.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There can be two reasons why your GPS location is null

1. May be your GPS is not active. Try to active your GPS from the `setting menu => Location & Security => Check Use GPS Satellites`.
2. May be you are currently in the building where the GPS is not working. Check it by coming out from the building. This can be happen most of time.

Comment: +1 yes, agree with you, please show full setting path in 1st option, it would be useful for new users like OP.:)

Answer (score 0):

As per [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html#getLastKnownLocation%28java.lang.String%29)

> If the provider is currently disabled, null is returned.

Ensure your GPS is active on the device so you don't receive null.

**Edit:**
Also try running `requestLocationUpdates()` with `GPS_PROVIDER` or maybe twice, with `NETWORK_PROVIDER` as well. The `LocationManager` retrieves the location the fastest way and it stops searching. Since GPS location is retrieved slower than the network location, is stops right after if finds it therefore returning null for the GPS.

Comment: NETWORK_PROVIDER is not linked to the GPS.

Comment: GPS is enabled and is working fine inside my building .. i have added  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_GPS"></uses-permission> . still its not working :(

Comment: @BalaKrishna I've edited the answer. Also, `ACCESS_GPS` is not in use anymore, so you can remove it from the manifest file.

Answer (score 0):

> The location turns null when i replace "NETWORK_PROVIDER" by
>   "GPS_PROVIDER"

**To solve this issue be sure to have enabled the Location services**:

[image]

remember the docs:

> **If the provider is currently disabled, null is returned.**

As an option you can use both providers if GPS is disabled then check network provider:

```
...
 myLocation = lm.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
 if(myLocation == null) {
            myLocation = lm.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
 }

    if(myLocation != null) {
         //Get values for latitude and longitude!
    }
...
```